# How to import the Gmail Address book using "Gmail Contact API" in IPhone?

Tags: iphone

I have an application in which i need to take the adreessbook(contact list)of user from gmail.
I added GData API to my application.and successfully done the login process and recieved the acesstoken from the auth2. I went through the contact sample given inside the GData API.But i was unable to get it.can anybody tell me how to fetch the contact list from gmail(steps to achieve it through GData API).Any help will be greately appreciated.